# Surfaces containing curves of arbitrarily negative self-intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces, complex-geometry

Olivier Wittenberg and I are curious about the following :

Let $S$ be a smooth projective complex surface. Are the self-intersection numbers of integral curves on $S$ always bounded below ? Or can $S$ contain integral curves with arbitrarily high negative self-intersection ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a folklore conjecture that surfaces in characteristic zero has bounded negativity. For a nice account of this problem and references, see the two survey articles

[Global aspects of the geometry of surfaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4151%20) by Harbourne, and

[Recent developments and open problems in linear series](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4363) by Bauer et al.

In positive characteristic however, the situation is different and there is a nice counterexample due to Kollar (taken from the 2nd paper above):

Let $C$ be a smooth curve of genus $g\geq 2$ defined over a field
   of characteristic $p>0$ and let $X$ be the product surface $X=C\times C$.
   The graph $\Gamma_q$ of the Frobenius morphism defined by taking
   $q=p^r$--th powers is a smooth
   curve of genus $g$ and self-intersection $\Gamma_q^2=q(2-2g)$.
   With $r$ going to infinity, we obtain a sequence of smooth curves
   of fixed genus with self-intersection going to minus infinity.

Answer (score 16):

In characteristic 0 this seems to be open, but conjecturally true: a reference is Conjecture I.2.1 in [this paper by Harbourne](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4151). As mentioned in that paper, it is definitely false in positive characteristic, as one might expect.

**Update:** Surprisingly, this long-standing conjecture has recently been disproved! Theorem A in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1881) (by many authors) says the following:

*Theorem A: There exists a smooth projective complex surface containing a sequence of negative curves whose self-intersections tend to $-\infty$.*

The counterexamples are related to Hilbert modular surfaces.

Let me also note that in the same paper the authors prove the following complementary theorem:

*Theorem B: For every integer $m>0$, there exists smooth projective complex surfaces containing infinitely many curves of self-intersection $-m$.*

**Update 2 (04/12):** As John L. points out, now the authors have retracted the claimed Theorem A above. So the Bounded Negativity Conjecture is back on the cards.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW sorry about the duplicate --- I guess J.C. and I composed our answers at the same time.

Comment: Hey Artie, good edit. That paper by Bauer et al. has some very interesting results indeed.  

Comment: There is a basic problem with the couterexamples of the six author paper, at least the current version on arXiv. They use the "fact" that if $f:X \to Y$ is an etale map of surfaces, then the image of a smooth curve is smooth!

Comment: The updated version of the paper removes the claim of a counterexample: arxiv.org/abs/1109.1881 Maybe it's true after all!